# Yii2 Client Side Validation

Tags: javascript, java, validation, yii2, conditional-statements

In Yii2 I have a conditional validation in the model.php. 
When I write in the textfield something that doesn't pass the validation, it doesn't appear an error message after leaving the field. 
Only after a *klick* on *create* an error message appears.
What do I have to make a message appears after writing something in a field.

```
<?php
['state', 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
    return $model->country == 'USA';
}, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
    return $('#country').val() == 'USA';
}"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model:

```
 public function rules()
 {
    return [
        ['state', 'required', 'targetClass' => '\backend\models\State', 
        'message' => 'Your message here'],
    ];
 }
```

I am not sure that your model is in backend, so you can correct that as you want.

In Controller you have to create function like that:

```
public function actionValidation(){
    $model = new State();
    if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->
    request->post())){
        Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }     
}
```

An one more step, in your form on the beginning:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(
                [
                    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
                    'validationUrl' => Url::toRoute('state/validation')
                ]
        ); ?>
```

Be careful, in code above I wrote 'state/validation', 'state' is name of controller where you put validation action.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `enableAjaxValidation` in ActiveForm

For example:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'contact-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i have described the problem not so good so I try it again.
The problem is that the conditional validation only works after a *click* on save/create.